# XNA Game Classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, xna-4.0

Since I need mulitple screens, 1) can I define more than one game class(inherited from Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game and with different class names). 2) is there any design flaws creating in such way?

Comment: Interesting question. Usual approach is creating a FSM (Finite State Machine) so each screen is one state. That means having only one game class. But not sure if it is possible to have multiple.

Comment: Its fine to have a single Game class. You can have different DrawingComponent for different screens.

Comment: @Shashwat, we can have multiple Game classes for each screen instead of -based on state, switching between the screen objects. if I am wrong please let me know the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible on Windows Phone 7. The platform starts an XNA game by finding a class derived from `Game` to instance (unlike Xbox and Windows where you create the instance yourself). I suspect it will fail if you have more than one derived class. (You could try it.)

Then there is the issue of the `GraphicsDevice`. I suspect it's not possible to set up two instances of the graphics device on WP7. How do you change which one can write to the screen? I'm not aware of any API for doing this.

Also, if you did have two separate graphics devices - you couldn't share content between the two. You would have to load it twice - a performance issue.

In theory you can set up two instances of `Game` to use the one `GraphicsDevice`. But that involves writing your own replacement version of `GraphicsDeviceManager`. That's not an easy task - and certainly much harder than simply setting up a simple state machine to handle your different screens.

Perhaps check out the [Game State Management](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management) sample for an example of how it's supposed to be done.

Answer (score 0):

The program starts by initializing the `Game1` class which inherits the `Game` class. So I don't think its a good idea to change that automatic code.

Moreover, as the name suggests; if you have multiple `Game` classes, that means you are running multiple "Games". But this is not the case. Instead, you do have multiple screens in a single `Game`.

To separate those screens, you can have different `DrawableGameComponent`. It also contains its own `Draw` and `Update` methods which you can implement.
Later you can add all those `DrawableGameComponent`s in `Components` list [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.components.aspx) of `Game1`.

All the complexity would be distributed among `DrawableGameComponent`s. Their `Draw` and `Update` method would be called automatically by XNA.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196942.aspx) can be helpful.

I think this to be a good way. Any better suggestions are welcome